# Interrupt Thread

Tags: multithreading

Can any body tell what is the purpose of using interrupt method of thread. Why we call interrupt method during execution??

Thanks

Comment: More importantly, what language?

Answer (score 0):

You call the interrupt method to interrupt the thread *if it's in a blocking state*... usually you interrupt a thread that's in a blocking state because it's either taking too long or your system is shutting down and you want to cancel whatever that thread is doing. Interrupt offers a "graceful" way to terminate a *blocking* thread, because it raises an interrupt exception and it's presumed that your thread is handing that exception. When your thread gets the interrupt exception, then it should gracefully terminate (i.e. clean up the state and exit any loops).

P.S. What programming language are you using?

Comment: In Java, calling `interrupt` on a thread raises an interrupt exception only if the thread is sleeping or waiting (possibly for I/O). It does not actually interrupt a compute-bound thread. However, a properly designed, compute-bound thread will periodically check whether the interrupt flag has been set and exit either quietly or by throwing an exception.

Comment: Ah... yes, I forgot to mention that. Thanks for reminding me! The Interrupt only affects a thread if it's in a blocking state.

Comment: In Java, blocking IO (at least `java.io`, I don't know about NIO) is __not__ interrupted by `Thread#interrupt()`.